# Missing file (net.xml) in Running Environment Flow

Tags: reinforcement-learning, sumo, flow-project

On tutorial 01 from flow:[Tutorial 01](https://github.com/flow-project/flow/blob/master/tutorials/tutorial01_sumo.ipynb).

I executed the code

```
flow_params = dict(
    exp_tag='ring_example',
    env_name=AccelEnv,
    network=RingNetwork,
    simulator='traci',
    sim=sim_params,
    env=env_params,
    net=net_params,
    veh=vehicles,
    initial=initial_config,
    tls=traffic_lights,
)

# number of time steps
flow_params['env'].horizon = 3000
exp = Experiment(flow_params)

# run the sumo simulation
_ = exp.run(1, convert_to_csv=True)
```

I got an error afterward, here is the error

```
Error during start: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '.../kernel/network/debug/cfg/ring_example_20201208-1332481607405568.58399.net.xml' Retrying in 1 seconds...
```

How should it be generated or where can it be found?

Answer (score 0):

This is an issue with my file naming conversion. Apparently, the command to be called in

```
        subprocess.call(
        [
            'netconvert -c "' + self.net_path + self.cfgfn +
            '" --output-file="' + self.cfg_path + self.netfn +
            '" --no-internal-links="false"'
        ],
        stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL,
        shell=True)
```

requires no spacing. In my case, I have my folder named "Machine Learning."